# Why is my header include file making the build fail?

Tags: header, spi, atmelstudio, arduino-due

I am trying to include the spi.h file in my project for an Arduino Due. I want to use Atmel Studio 6.2 since it offers me more flexibility and is frankly a much better IDE than the Arduino tool. I can sucessfully program the board using bossa.exe programming utility called from a batch file which communicates with the Arduino. This is the basic call from the batch file:

```
C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Arduino\hardware\tools\bossac.exe --port=%1 -U false -e -w -v -b %2 -R
```

Now the issue is, Atmel studio works just fine to program the board if code is left like this:

```
 #include "sam.h"

 int main(void)
 {
     /* Initialize the SAM system */
     SystemInit();

     while (1) 
     {
         //TODO:: Please write your application code 
     }
 }
```

BUT the minute I do this:

```
 #include "spi.h"
```

the build fails...

```
spi.h: No such file or directory
```

BUT when I look in the solution explorer, I can see the sam.h file:

[image]

So whats going on here?

(**EDIT:** I forgot to show the sam.h file in the screen shot, but trust me, its in the folder called "Dependencies")

Comment: where is your `spi.h` file?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to show it in the screen shot, but the file is under the "Dependencies" folder...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `spi.h` header file. Are you sure you have the file available in your machine?

Answer (score 0):

`#include "header.h"` will look for the header file in the *same directory* as the file it is being included from (usually, the .c).

`#include <header.h>` will look for the header in the *system-wide* standard header include directory.

You can also add custom include search paths for your compiler. Verify that `spi.h` is available in a location your compiler is aware of!

I don't know the specifics of the IDE you are using, but "Dependencies" seems like a virtual collection of files, not a physical folder.